# Getting uncaught error in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When I'm doing the right click option for more than 5 (approx) times for certain task, it showing uncaught error as like below:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Class.<anonymous> (core.js:21487)
    at fn (core.js:7779)
    at DeferredActionQueues.flush (core.js:7723)
    at Backburner.end (core.js:7738)
    at Backburner.run (core.js:7748)
    at executeTimers (core.js:7824)
    at core.js:7822
```

In that Place I'm having the below code:

```
Ember.run.later(view, function () {
    this.$().find('menu-item:eq(0)').focus();
}, 125);
```

Can anyone please suggest me why this error is coming and I need to avoid this error while right clicking the task for "n" number of time also. I'm new to the ember. Your help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats a simple javascript issue. In the second line `this.$()` returns `undefined`, and so it can't call `.find` on undefined.

More interesting is *why* `this.$()` is undefined. Probably you have this code inside a component, and try to access the local [`jQuery` instance](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Component/methods/$?anchor=%24). However you call it inside an anonymous `function(){}`, which breaks your `this`-context (because it gets a new one).

The best solution here is to use an arrow function:

```
Ember.run.later(view, () => {
  this.$().find('menu-item:eq(0)').focus();
}, 125);
```

this prevents the outer `this` context, which is nice. Another options is to save this:

```
const self = this;
Ember.run.later(view, function () {
  self.$().find('menu-item:eq(0)').focus();
}, 125);
```

Or you can `.bind(this)`:

```
Ember.run.later(view, (function () {
  this.$().find('menu-item:eq(0)').focus();
}).bind(this), 125);
```

I can definitely recommend the first option, especially when using ember(-cli) which gives you transpilation anyway.